# Using variables within cmake-gui

Tags: variables, cmake

I am using cmake-gui to create a Visual Studio Solution. My directory structure looks something like this:

```
Foo
|-- source
|-- include
|-- docs
|-- // ...
|-- bin   // desired output directory
|-- build // cmake build directory
```

I want to set the output directory for the generated projects to be located at the following location: `Foo/bin`.

If I understand correctly, the cmake variable [PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html) contains the absolute path to the "Foo" directory shown in the directory diagram above. Using cmake-gui, I'm trying to set `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`to the value of `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/static/$(Platform)/$(Configuration)`

Where `$(Platform)` and `$(Configuration)` are Visual Studio macros.

This does not produce the expected result. The problem is that CMake does not substitute "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}" with its value, meaning in the generated .vcxproj the output directory value is literally: "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/static/$(Platform)/$(Configuration)"

Simply put, my question is: How can CMake variables be used in cmake-gui?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, CMake-GUI does not evaluate variables or macros. You can only add actual paths (relative or absolute). If you would like to use variables, you have to modify your CMakeLists.txt.

If you call CMake from the command line, you could add `-D FENCY_VARIABLE=bin/static/$(Platform)/$(Configuration)` which would be evaluated by your terminal.